# Strange scoping issue when using typeguards

Tags: typescript, types

Say we have this typescript code:

```
interface A { 
  bar: string;
}
const isA = <T>(obj: T): obj is T & A => {
  obj['bar'] = 'world';
  return true;
}

let obj = { foo: 'hello' };
if (!isA(obj)) throw 'wont ever throw'

obj.foo // This is ok
obj.bar // This is ok

Array(5).fill(0).forEach((_, i) => {
  obj.foo // This is ok
  obj.bar // This is not ok
});
```

Why is `obj.bar` not valid while inside the `forEach`?

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20A%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20bar%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20isA%20%3D%20%3CT%3E(obj%3A%20T)%3A%20obj%20is%20T%20%26%20A%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20obj%5B'bar'%5D%20%3D%20'world'%3B%0D%0A%20%20return%20true%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%3A%20'hello'%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aif%20(!isA(obj))%20throw%20'wont%20ever%20throw'%0D%0A%0D%0Aobj.foo%20%2F%2F%20This%20is%20ok%0D%0Aobj.bar%20%2F%2F%20This%20is%20ok%0D%0A%0D%0AArray(5).fill(0).forEach((_%2C%20i)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20obj.foo%20%2F%2F%20This%20is%20ok%0D%0A%20%20obj.bar%20%2F%2F%20This%20is%20not%20ok%0D%0A%7D)%3B)

Comment: relevant: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7719#issuecomment-202684512

Comment: also relevant: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11498

Comment: @jcalz That makes sense, thanks for showing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general answer is that you are cleverer than the compiler in this case.  TypeScript uses heuristics to [analyze the control flow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis) of the code to try to infer narrower types for expressions.  It does a reasonable job of this, but [it isn't perfect](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) and probably can never be.

When you access `obj.bar` immediately after throwing if `isA(obj)` returns `false`, the compiler narrows `obj` to include `A`, as you expect.  Unfortunately, when you create a closure and pass it to `Array.prototype.forEach()`, the compiler widens `obj` back to its original type which does not include `A`.  Now you and I know that `forEach()` will immediately invoke its callback function, but TypeScript doesn't.  For all it knows, the value of `obj` will be modified before the callback is invoked.  And there's no way to [tell](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11498) the compiler differently.  So it decides that narrowing isn't safe and gives up.

So, workarounds: one idea is to make `obj` a `const` instead of declaring it with `let`:

```
const obj = { foo: 'hello' };
if (!isA(obj)) throw 'wont ever throw'
Array(5).fill(0).forEach((_, i) => {
  obj.bar // This is okay now
});
```

This doesn't actually change the fact that `obj.bar` can be added or removed before a callback that closes over `obj` is called, but the heuristic that TypeScript uses is something like "`const` is more likely to be immutable than `let`", even though [it's not, really](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-const).

A similar workaround, if you can't make `obj` a `const`, is to assign a new `const` variable after the narrowing takes place, and use that in the callback instead:

```
let obj = { foo: 'hello' };
if (!isA(obj)) throw 'wont ever throw'
const myObj = obj;    
Array(5).fill(0).forEach((_, i) => {
  myObj.bar // This is okay
});
```

Of course by that token you might as well skip the `obj` middleman entirely:

```
let obj = { foo: 'hello' };
if (!isA(obj)) throw 'wont ever throw'
const bar = obj.bar;    
Array(5).fill(0).forEach((_, i) => {
  bar // This is okay
});
```

It's up to you.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!